# Revealing bid for .eth domain doesn't work

Tags: ens

I placed a bid on an .eth domain and now the revealing period started. I revealed my bid according to this documentation:

```
https://docs.ens.domains/en/latest/userguide.html#revealing-your-bid
```

with the following command:

```
ethRegistrar.unsealBid(web3.sha3('name'), web3.toWei(1, 'ether'), web3.sha3('mypassword'), {from: eth.accounts[0], gas: 500000});
```

After I executed the command in geth I got a hash. When I enter the hash in etherscan.io I don't see any transaction there. If I check the domain on registrar.ens.domains the Current highest bidder is still 0.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The problem is solved. For some reason it took almost one hour for the transaction to show up on etherscan.io. Why did it take so long?

Comment: i took so long because of the congestion due to the BAT Ico.

Comment: Now I'm trying to reveal a bid on another domain which I registered and the transaction failed again. Is there still a congestion problem? What should I do?

Comment: Can you give me the domain name or the tx hash. I can't do much without informations

Comment: hash:   0x5f95f99426225f2c36e6c64bfe969edb4942c7392822bb183712191a65803ab5

Comment: You might want to increase the gwei. If the transaction is not visible it might mean it is not mined yet. My ether wallet allow this easily.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59672/discussion-between-bumblebee-and-crema).